# change img size inside iframe with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, iframe

I'm using an adserver on my website. All adds are using iframe, and I'm trying to target the img (the first one with width = 728 & height = 90) inside the iframe to change its size (width & height).
I've been able to target the body (changing its background color to test), but I can't target the image to change its size.
here is the iframe code, I need to target the iframe object, and not the iframe class, because the class changes every time.

```
<div class="insert_pub">
  <iframe id="a0811af3" width="" height="90" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=3&cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE" name="a0811af3">
    #document
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <a href="/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=212__zoneid=3__cb=9b2dbdb22f__oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fthebayfestival.fr%2F" target="_blank">
          <img src="/www/images/c34d3222b19118f97aa99e76310c70fe.jpg" alt="" title="" height="90" border="0" width="728">
        </a>
        <div id="beacon_9b2dbdb22f" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;">
          <img src="/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=212&amp;campaignid=176&amp;zoneid=3&amp;loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mmdwc.com%2Fmagazine%2F&amp;cb=9b2dbdb22f" alt="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;" height="0" width="0">
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

here is what I've tried, but it's not working :

```
function iframe_insert_size() {
  $(".insert_pub iframe").contents().find("img").css({"width":624, "height" : 77});
}
```

Comment: are you even running the function ?

Answer (score 4):

You have acces to your iFrame with next sentence:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {

                 $("#a0811af3").on('load', function () {

 $("#a0811af3").contents().find("your image").on("click", function (e) {

              });
       });
});
```

This case works when you do it click inside an image.
It's rigth?, It's what you need?

Comment: I need the image to be resized on load, not when clicking, and I can't target the ID of the iframe, cause it will change, I need to target all iframes

Comment: there is still a click function, I need the css to change without having to click